# Shut down Mac Server when APC 1400 battery is nearly empty

Tags: macos, usb, mac-mini, osx-server, ups

I'm running OS X Server on a Mac Mini. I'm powering the server via an APC 1400 (one of the older, beige ones). It has a serial connector, so I assume it could possibly interface with the Mac Mini via a serial to USB adapter.

Is it possible to power down the OS X Server when the UPS batter is nearly depleted with my setup? Do I need to install APC software to get this to work? Will a serial to USB adapter do the job?

Or is my APC backup unit too ancient to work with my Mac Mini in this scenario?

Comment: can you link to the APC manual for your specific item? A photo of the connector and/or serial number part of the unit might help us help you further than the generic answer I posted affirming the OS is ready to go with no additional software installed.

Comment: You could try [this 9-pin D-sub - USB serial cable](http://www.amazon.com/Generic-9-pin-Serial-Port-Adapter/dp/B001J226JQ) to see if the UPS can communicate with your Mac. In the past, APC had PowerChute software which communicated with the UPS. Perhaps Mac OS X will see the UPS natively with this cable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any software on the Mac for most APC units. The OS detects them when plugged into USB in my experience and the energy saver preference pane has exactly the control you seek:

[image]

[image]

You can see the connection is USB and the firmware details on the device.

Comment: The OP's UPS only has a serial input.

Comment: @IconDaemon USB is serial - it really depends on the protocol and connection whether you need a RS-232 to talk to that older unit. Mine is USB to RJ45 but I've seen RJ11 and similar work with USB in the data centers I've frequented.

Comment: I'm aware that USB is serial, but APC 1400s are pretty old devices and may require the old (and outdated PowerChute) software. The older APC 1400s used a 9-pin D-sub connector. I commented to the OP with a a link to a $5 9-pin - USB connector from Amazon.